# How to make a required form field blank in javaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head>  
<meta charset="UTF-8">  
<title>Form</title>         
<script> 

    function billingFunction()
    {
        var shippingName = document.getElementById("shippingName");

        if(document.getElementById("same").checked )
        {
            document.getElementById("billingName").value= shippingName.value;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("billingName").removeAttribute("required");
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>  

    <form>      
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Shipping Information</legend>             
            <label for ="shippingName">Name:</label>          
            <input type = "text" name = "Name" id = "shippingName" required><br/>
        </fieldset>

        <input type="checkbox" id="same" name="same" onchange= "billingFunction()"/>        
        <label for = "same">Is the Billing Information the Same?</label>                        

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Billing Information</legend>              
            <label for ="billingName">Name:</label>       
            <input type = "text" name = "Name" id = "billingName" required><br/>
        </fieldset>

    <input type = "submit" value = "Verify"/>   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever the checkbox is checked, the code should automatically copy the values from first field into the second field.  If the checkbox is unchecked, the second one should go blank. as per my code the first requirement is ok, but I couldn't make it blank when it is unchecked. Can anyone help plz.

Comment: Really, you couldn't do `.value = "";`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ry90m7u6/

Comment: There is one thing wrong with your code. Please consider not to open curly bracket in new line. You could get a load of strange bugs like returning nothing when you wanted to return an object.

Comment: @Rouz there is nothing wrong with that.. Its a matter of choice!!

Comment: @SujeetSinha Not in JavaScript because the semicolon is optional. In C it is a matter of choice. In JavaScript it can introduce strange bugs.

Comment: @Rouz can you point me to any source for that? I haven't encountered any such issues myself..

Comment: @Rouz - nope, the above syntax is completely valid, you can open curlybraces on any line you want.

Comment: @adeneo https://www.toptal.com/javascript/interview-questions Check the question #6

Comment: @SujeetSinha check the above link

Comment: @Rouz - That's all fine and well, when using `return`, IIFE's, and probably many other things, insertion of semi-colons can trip you up, but that doesn't mean curlybraces used like in the question above is invalid, it is in fact completely valid, and not a problem, as long as one knows where not to use it.

Comment: and of course if you please https://jsfiddle.net/uo5kfb30/ look at the code that should support what I have written. It is bad but it is JS after all

Comment: @Rouz - You're still wrong, I can write a million examples where automatic insertion of semi-colons is an issue, but it's not in the code above, and it's still ***completely valid***.

Comment: @adeneo i second that

Comment: @adeneo Of course it is valid. And a matter of choice. But this way of writing code can introduce a head banging bug. So therefore I suggested to consider a switch to another code style.

Comment: @Rouz - no you didn't, you said *"There is one thing wrong with your code..."*, but how someone chooses to format their code isn't a problem that would cause an error, it's just your opinion that curlybraces should be on the same line etc. and I agree with you, I would place them on the same line as well, but it's not a problem if someone chooses not do so.

Comment: Douglas Crockford suggests not to use this coding style because Quote: "I always use the K&R style, putting the { at the end of a line instead of the front, because it avoids a horrible design blunder in JavaScript's return statement.". And I also said "Please consider not to open curly bracket in new line." It is not like I said that the OP is wrong per se but that it can lead to unwanted behavior and bugs in code.

Comment: What Mr. Crockpot suggests, is his own opinion, and it's still valid, and not an issue, you just can't win.

Comment: @adeneo It is not important whether I win or not. I am saying that it is easier to make a mistake with that coding style although the style is valid. I understand what you are saying and you are right - but I still strongly believe that for JavaScript language K&R style should be suggested (not enforced).

Answer (score 0):

You only need to modify the `else` block

```
else{
            document.getElementById("billingName").value="";
        }
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/w2wj159y/1/)

**EDIT**

You have put the `billing` function inside header. You must be comming across reference error.

You can put this billing function inside `window.onload` or pu this script near closing `body` tag

```
window.onload= function(){
billingFunction;
} 

function billingFunction(){ //Rest of code}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/w2wj159y/2/) with window.onload

Comment: Thanks, I tried with this code too, but I am sorry that it is not working too for my form..

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having the function within the header though? Both of our Fiddles work..

Answer (score 0):

Add `document.getElementById("billingName").value = null;` to the else clause.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gus1f1vv/)

Comment: Thanks, but at first I tried with this code given by you..but sorry it didn't work for me..I am not sure what is wrong with my code..

Comment: But the Fiddle works? You must have other issues not relating to the code you have presented - are you using anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value to an empty string in the `else` clause

```
function billingFunction() {
    var shippingName = document.getElementById("shippingName");
    var billingName  = document.getElementById("billingName");

    if(document.getElementById("same").checked ) {
        billingName.value = shippingName.value;
    } else {
        billingName.removeAttribute("required");
        billingName.value = "";
    }
}
```